# How to apply styles to react-date-picker based on condition?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In a React project I've certain date fields which is mapped from JSON data and displayed on grid. Here I'm using `react-date-picker` package for Date. My intention is to apply background color to certain date field with some condition, but, it applies to all date fields. Please go through the code below for clarity

DynamicTable.js (Component file)

```
<DatePicker...
className={moment(this.props.rows[row.id].pickdate).format("MM/DD/YYYY") =="06/20/2020" ? 
"react-date-picker__inputGroup" : ""}
...
```

style.css (style file)

```
.react-date-picker__inputGroup {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

As seen from above code snippet, I'm applying background color to only specific date field i.e(20/06/2020) with `react-date-picker__inputGroup` which is `className` style for react-date-picker, but, its getting applied to all date fields. What is the best solution to apply conditional styling?

[image]

See the image above

Please also refer to Codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-moon-0hkhi4?file=/src/DynamicTable.js:1830-1859

Comment: "My intention is to apply background color to certain date field with some condition", can you please mention the condition, or a demo?

Comment: Here `react-date-picker__inputGroup` className is already inbuilt for the datepicker input from the library `react-date-picker`.

So, you need to change the className to some other name like, `react-date-picker__inputWrapper` . Also change the css class selector accordingly. Forked example: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-silence-o914t3

Answer (score 1):

I have renamed the specific `className`.

```
<DatePicker
  ...
className={moment(this.props.rows[row.id].pickdate).format("MM/DD/YYYY") =="06/20/2020" ? 
"react-date-picker__customized" : ""}

... ... ...

.react-date-picker__customized {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Hope this would be helpful for you.
Please have a look [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-morning-ot1qdz).